# Remove "Cart updated" from Checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I found the links below, but none of them worked for me:

[Remove "Added to cart" and "Cart updated" message on Checkout for WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916716/remove-added-to-cart-and-cart-updated-message-on-checkout-for-woocommerce/68085039#68085039)

To remove "[Product] has been added to your cart."
[Hide Added to Cart message in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37126658/hide-added-to-cart-message-in-woocommerce)

Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: Do you use a certain theme or plugin that has influence on WooCommerce (for example, it edits the templates)?

We really need more info on this, like the things you have tried and how.

Comment: I tried the links I sent! The themes don't influence on it!